# Добавить столбец со значением зависящим от условия

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дано:

```
  In [10]: df      
  Out[10]:
    a  b  
0   1  1      
1   2  2     
2   1  2
```

Как можно добавить новый столбец `c`, в котором будут либо `1` либо `0`? Если сумма `a + b > 2.5`, то 1, в противном случае 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['c'] = np.where(df['a'] + df['b'] > 2.5, 1, 0)
```

Как-то так

Comment: Да, получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите, а как будет выглядеть запись, если нужно записать 1, в случае если сумма больше 2, 0, если меньше и 2, если сумма равна 2?

Comment: df['c'] = np.where(df['a'] + df['b'] > 2, 1, np.where(df['a'] + df['b'] < 2, 0, 2))

Answer (score 4):

```
df["c"] = (df["a"] + df["b"] > 2.5).astype("int8")
```

---

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  0
1  2  2  1
2  1  2  1

In [5]: df.dtypes
Out[5]:
a    int64
b    int64
c     int8
dtype: object
```